# Magnolia 5.5.5 Indexing Config In Magnolia

Tags: maven, lucene, content-management-system, jackrabbit, magnolia

Right now I have my

> indexing_configuration.xml

and my

> workspace.xml

in my workspace/website folder. When I do a `mvn clean` the workspace will be reset resulting in this config disappearing.

How can I include the configuration in my magnolia project so that it gets installed when I redeploy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In magnolia.properties file there is a parameter for setting jackrabbit configuration file, typically it's

```
magnolia.repositories.jackrabbit.config=WEB-INF/config/repo-conf/jackrabbit-bundle-derby-search.xml
```

In this file, you can set a custom path for configuration files. For indexing it's in **SearchIndex** section, param name **indexingConfiguration**.

If you want to use different configurations for different workspaces, you can add extra **Workspace** sections. But I haven't tried it yet.

Some documentation how it works you can find here: [Jackrabbit Repository Configuration File](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/WIKI/Jackrabbit+Repository+Configuration+File)